# How to delete the kubernetes provider accounts which is attached to a cluster.(that cluster is deleted)

Tags: spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

I have  many kubernetes provider accounts.  out of them  two are 1) my-k8s-account and 2) my-test-account... both are attached to same kubernetes cluster. Now I had to delete the cluster. Now I am trying to *sudo hal deploy apply* (Now its showing namespaces not found error with my-k8s-account). So I tried to run *hal config kubernetes provider delete my-k8s-account* and its throwing the error issues with my-test-account. I tried to delete both with the same command even that didnot work

can anyone help me

Issue link in GitHUB

https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker.github.io/issues/996

Comment: We can use this tag no-validate so that iit will skip checking the config details of the clusters    #hal config provider kubernetes account delete ACCOUNT --no-validate

Answer (score 0):

We can use this tag `no-validate` so that it will skip checking the config details of the clusters:

```
#hal config provider kubernetes account delete ACCOUNT --no-validate
```